# Using Mysql query with where condition

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have decoded the Json and now want to submit in the database,

How can i use this query with where condition?

```
if(is_array($arr)){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_title, post_type) values ";

    $valuesArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $row){

        $email = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['property_name'] );
        $post = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['post_type'] );

        $valuesArr[] = "('$email', '$post')";


    }

    $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

    mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Comment: INSERT WHERE !?!?!?! Do you mean UPDATE?

Comment: yes update query.. sorry

Comment: Well maybe start with an UPDATE then !

Comment: var_dump($arr) to check whether it is the expected two dimensional array or not

Comment: check this link. you should stop using `mysql_*` functions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(is_array($arr)){
    $valuesArr = array();
    foreach($arr as $row){
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['property_name'] );
        $post = mysql_real_escape_string( $row['post_type'] );
        $sql = "update wp_posts set post_title='".$email."', post_type='".$post."' where X=Y";
        mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error()); 
    }
}`